# Do we have posts that would be worth advertising?

Tags: discussion

In the aim of bringing more people to SE, the powers that be have decided to revitalize the main [SE twitter account](https://twitter.com/StackExchange).

They then asked us mods to propose questions from our sites that might be worthy of being shared by said accounts.

Ideally these posts show how we work and the knowledge we can share:

> We want to use the Twitter account to draw attention to a bunch of stuff but what we need your help with is:
>
> - **Awesome/interesting/fun Questions & Answers**
>     We'll feature a few of these per week and try to make sure that they're representative of a broad collection of our sites. This includes notable meta posts, too - though I'm guessing they'll be infrequent.
> - **Site events/contests**
>     If a site has a regular or one-off event, we may be able to tweet about some of them. Some of y'all do events throughout the year and we'd love to share some of the community-led fun.
> - **Users who do noteworthy work or meet celebratory rep levels**
>     *We won't Tweet about anyone without reaching out to them first*... but if there's someone you think deserves (and would appreciate) a spotlight on what they've been doing, either on main and/or meta, let us know.

So, please feel free to answer this post with whatever question you think should be shared.

**NOTE:** this post will not "expire". At any time in the future you should encounter a good question/answer, please post it here!

Comment: Notable mention for fun and interesting: * https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/8051/14897

Answer (score 6):

I think some of the more canonical questions might be worthy, for example:

[How complete is our understanding of lift?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/21664/how-complete-is-our-understanding-of-lift)

[What is the significance of a squawk code?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/14570/what-is-the-significance-of-a-squawk-code)

[Can Microsoft Flight Simulator help me learn to fly (or make me a better pilot)?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/738/can-microsoft-flight-simulator-help-me-learn-to-fly-or-make-me-a-better-pilot) (Every budding aviator has at some point pondered this!)

[Can a passenger realistically replace suddenly incapacitated pilots?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8986/can-a-passenger-realistically-replace-suddenly-incapacitated-pilots) (Every aviator has at some point fantasised about this!)

[Why are the cockpit controls of airplanes so complicated?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/2873/why-are-the-cockpit-controls-of-airplanes-so-complicated)

[Why is "Affirm / Negative" used instead of "Yes / No"?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/25736/why-is-affirm-negative-used-instead-of-yes-no)

[Why do we still use pilots to fly airplanes?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/1802/why-do-we-still-use-pilots-to-fly-airplanes)

Answer (score 1):

My first vote would be 
[Is this plane landing or departing?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/34586/is-this-plane-landing-or-departing)

It shows we are aviation site and not a forum. We don’t a one word answer. Top vote answer may not be the fastest but the most comprehensive, to the point and with supporting evidence. I think that say much about our site.

This is a **fun**-type of question to me.

Comment: On the other hand, despite the supporting evidence, the highest-voted answer turned out to be wrong. - haha

Comment: Haha i have not checked that in detail. But for advertising purpose it seems good enough for me ;) let’s look for more question/answer to promote!!

Comment: If that was the first question I'd have seen after arriving on this site, I would think less of the site than when noticing an unambiguously answered question. This is a site for clearly-stated questions with clearly-stated answers, and that question isn't a particularly good example in that regard. It's an interesting question, sure, but not one fit for advertisement IMO.

Comment: Please don't disseminate questions where the accepted answer is wrong. We have too many of those here already.

Comment: I don't understand the criticism for the most voted answer (there is no accepted answer). it clearly ends with "This has to be a landing", and it is indeed a landing

Answer (score 1):

Just looking through my own questions and I think those two would be interesting to a broader audience:

[Is it possible to install a bike rack on a Cessna 172?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/46737/is-it-possible-to-install-a-bike-rack-on-a-cessna-172)

[How much is airspeed reduced on an A10-Warthog when firing its cannon?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/46317/how-much-is-airspeed-reduced-on-an-a10-warthog-when-firing-its-cannon)

Answer (score 1):

[What is a TRACON?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/25212/1696)

Fairly broad question, the answer covers it well and includes lots of good pictures.

Comment: Submitted to the team behind the account

Answer (score 0):

A couple aircraft identification questions where the answer tracks down the specific airframe in question and its history:

[What is that decommissioned plane near Nadirgul Airfield?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/48543/1696)

[What is this aircraft with elaborate folding wings?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/33544/1696)